# JDBC problems connectiong to sql server

Tags: java, jdbc

i'm trying to establishing a connection from java to sql server. I'm using jdk 8 1.8 and sql server 2014, and this is my code:

```
package test.prova;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class Provaconn {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");


        Connection m_Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://srvdatiorim14.saga.locale;DatabaseName=mydbname", "myuser", "mypw");

        Statement m_Statement = m_Connection.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM trasco_proprieta";

        ResultSet m_ResultSet = m_Statement.executeQuery(query);

        while (m_ResultSet.next()) {
          System.out.println(m_ResultSet.getString(1) + ", " + m_ResultSet.getString(2) + ", "
              + m_ResultSet.getString(3));

        }
      }
```

but i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at test.prova.Provaconn.main(Provaconn.java:10)
```

i've already searched for a solution in various topic, i've tried lot of various adjustment, but still i got this error. 
I've also imported the jdbc driver jar, from both maven dependency and external library (i tried different version of it as you can see):

[image]

any suggestion on how to solve this? T
Thank,
Serph

EDIT - SOLVED

after changing the Class.forName into te one suggest in the answer, i also modified the url which was wrong. Changed it from

jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://...

to

jdbc:sqlserver//...

Comment: It has to be on your classpath

Comment: Please check is the needed class in class path. 
On the screen I see 2 version of mssql jar. You should remove all jar dependencies added in project. Add dependency with maven and re-import the maven dependency with command:  mvn eclipse:eclipse

Comment: It was already in the classpath. I changed now che class forName as suggested in the answer and the error i got now is: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver...I've also removed the duplicated dependency and kept just the sqljdbc 4.2

Comment: As an aside, you are using a pretty old version of the driver (version 2.0). You may want to consider upgrading to a newer version (latest is 7.0 for Java 10 and higher, or 6.4 for Java 7, 8 and 9).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i have to work with java 8, so i just tried to follow your tip and put the jdbc 6.4 in the maven dependency. I removed the 4-2.0, and i didn't edit anything but that, and i got again the first error..maybe because i have to add the new one to the classpath again? how can i do that if it's managed by the maven dependencies?

Comment: That depends on exactly what you used as a maven dependency. Note that according to your screenshot you are using Java 7, not Java 8, so you need to make sure you add the java 7 dependency for SQL Server JDBC. You also seem to have added the SQL Server JDBC driver version 7 for Java 10: you'll need to remove that one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you use this jar file: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqljdbc420jar.htm
you must change:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
```

to

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```